# Embedded code will not display in WordPress page

Tags: javascript, html, wordpress, embed

I have some simple code that contains all of the html, css/styling, and javascript needed to display a web map in a browser. If I launch it from a file on my local, it opens up correctly in a browser and displays the web map. I am now trying to embed that code in a page using my WordPress editor/CMS.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.26/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.26/"></script>
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
<script>
  require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
    var map;
    require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
      map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "topo",
        center: [-122.45, 37.75],
        zoom: 13
      });
    });
  });
</script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

I tried installing a plugin called 'Scripts n Styles' that is suppose to help read the `<script>` tags, but still, it just displays as blank. This is a brand new Word Press installation so I am not sure if there is something else I need or if my code is just configured incorrectly. Any suggestions

Comment: Are you using the "Text" view in the editor

Comment: Yes, I'm using the text editor, not visual.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<meta>` tag is best added within the `<head>`, as does the `link` (although WP already has this viewport tag already so you can ignore it). You can add the rest within the page itself (on the text section - no need for a plugin). I'd recommend creating a new template, see: [WP Templates](https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/template-files-section/page-template-files/)

Console error shows multiple `defines`. I took out the seemingly duplicate `require` and it works fine on a page (copy/paste):

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://js.arcgis.com/3.26/esri/css/esri.css">
<style>
  html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
  }
</style>
<script src="https://js.arcgis.com/3.26/"></script>
<script src="https://requirejs.org/docs/release/2.3.5/minified/require.js"></script>
<script>
    var map;
    require(["esri/map", "dojo/domReady!"], function(Map) {
      map = new Map("map", {
        basemap: "topo",
        center: [-122.45, 37.75],
        zoom: 13
      });
    });
</script>

<div id="map"></div>
```

While this works, I'd still recommend putting it on a template.

Comment: OK, when I plug that into my text editor and publish it, it's still showing as blank. I created a new theme. I even tried putting the code at the page level in Scripts n Styles for the head section as suggested. When I check the browser console I am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined", so its not reading my cdn or something.

Comment: To be clear, you added the 2 scripts above (specifically the `minified/require.js`) and then the `require([...` call right below? I'd have to see the page/errors to know what is going on

Comment: OK, its working. Apparently, I had to publish first and it just took a minute to load.